# Сыновий или сыновний?

Tags: грамотная-речь, однокоренные-слова

Словари, которые я посмотрел, не дают каких-либо различий в этих словах. А как же "закон экономии языковых средств"?  Может, кто-то из участников форума видит какие-нибудь нюансы в этих двух словах?

Comment: Я вообще не слышала слово "сыновий". Что оно означает?

Comment: Большой толковый словарь: СЫНОВИЙ, -ья, -ье; СЫНОВНИЙ, -яя, -ее.
к Сын. С. долг. С-ья любовь. < По-сыновьи; по-сыновнему, нареч. По-сыновьи любить. По-сыновнему привязан к кому-л.
(как сын, как подобает сыну).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово СЫНОВНИЙ менее свободное, что ли. Чаще всего употребляется и ассоциируется со словом ДОЛГ, хотя и в других сочетаниях встречается, конечно.

Answer (score -1):

"Закон экономии" не имеет абсолютного характера. 
Кстати, вы его, часом, не путаете с "законом" устранения синонимичности?
Простите, но предположение основано на том, что для применения здесь упомянутого "закона экономии" нет разумных оснований. Один звук, простите, это несерьёзно. Что-то реальное можно разглядеть на уровне слога как минимальной единицы.

Comment: Обожаю анонимные минусы. )))

Comment: О законе экономии языковых средств я читал еще в студенческие годы, и этот термин мне запомнился. Не помню только автора. Кажется, Бодуэн-де-Куртене. А насчет одного звука с Вами не согласен. Я имел в виду не один звук добавочный, а целое дополнительное слово